# Loading a stdout into a variable in a line using tee

Tags: bash

I'm trying to put the amount of lines in a gzipped file in a variable, later on I plan to use this stdout for another process using tee. Why won't the value of wc -l get put into the variable and how can I fix this?

```
[]$ gzip -dc BC102.fastq.gz | wc -l
4255588
[]$ gzip -dc BC102.fastq.gz | echo $(wc -l)
4255588
[]$ gzip -dc BC102.fastq.gz | reads=$(wc -l); echo $reads
0
```

The whole line is eventually supposed to look like

```
gzip -dc BC102.fastq.gz | tee >(reads=$(wc -l)) | cutadapt -ga...
```

I don't see how this is a duplicate from [How to set a variable to the output from a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash) since I was already applying the answer listed there to echo the value of wc -l directly, but it won't be inserted into the variable.

Comment: @hek2mlg This is not a duplicate because the output shall be used *twice*.

Comment: @LutzHorn Of course it is a duplicate. Btw, I consider the question "What is the result of `1+2`" as a duplicate of the question "What is the result of `1+1`".

Comment: The question you think this is a duplicate of is only about capturing stdout in a variable. This question is about capturing the output *plus* using it in another pipe.

Comment: This is more like a duplicate, but I think there are better ones: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441868/how-do-i-read-standard-out-into-a-bash-variable-without-using-a-subshell-or-a-na

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`tee`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee) writes to stdout plus to all files given as arguments. It does not write to two different pipes you could attach to.

Try this:

```
t=$(tempfile)
reads=$(gzip -dc BC102.fastq.gz | tee $t | wc -l)
```

Now you can continue in your script

```
cutadapt -ga $t
```

while `reads` contains the number of lines.

Comment: Since I want to use 
`gzip -dc BC102.fastq.gz | tee >(reads=$(wc -l)) | cutadapt -ga...` I dont think I can use that.

Comment: Ah, I clearly misunderstood the use of tee. Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you set a variable in a subshell, it will have no effect on the parent. That is what happens with

```
gzip -dc BC102.fastq.gz | tee >(reads=$(wc -l)) | cutadapt -ga...
```

But nothing obvious stops you from continuing the pipe in the subshell:

```
reads=$(wc -l <(gzip -dc BC102.fastq.gz | tee >(cutadapt -ga... )))
```